# Android gradle dependency error for recyclerview

Tags: android

I am using following gradle dependancy:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.4.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
```

I am getting following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Can anyone help me out with the error... I tried changing appcompat version and compileSdkVersion but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

adding 'multiDexEnabled true' to default config in gradle solved the problem